# How to detect anonymous user?

Tags: php, facebook

How to detect anonymous user like facebook does, when you open it throught proxy websites like hidemyass.com. I think its something related to proxy, but beyond I dont know anything about it, but I want to create that.

Comment: so that I can try to block them like facebook does?

Comment: epal Still; why? Perhaps there is an alternative way to accomplish what you are ultimately after?

Comment: @bzlm, I can't give a reason for the reason? BTW can you tell me those alternative ways also, I would like to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common way to detect proxy servers is by looking if these [http headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) fields are empty (if not, a proxy is used to access you're webserver):

- HTTP_FORWARDED
- HTTP:X-Forwarded
- HTTP:Forwarded-For
- HTTP:X-Forwarded-For

In PHP you can read these values with the **[getenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)** function.

Comment: BTW this will not detect real stealth proxies and that it also detects proxies that are in use at companies, schools, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say who is trying to hide his identity and who has limited/restricted access based on firewall rules etc. You can also check if user accept COOKIES by sending special token on first request and fetching on second.